# Calling controller method from directive in template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is sitting in a template that is then included on a page.

If I place my directive directly onto my page, then on a button click I can call a method within my controller.

However, when I place the directive within a template, and then the template on the page, I can no longer call a method in my controller from the directive.

I've tried a number of things with the posted code below my latest attempt.  However, this code produces the error

> asking for new/isolated scope on:

So HTML first;

This is on my HTML page.

```
<session-list trackid='san'></session-list>
```

This is the template HTML;

```
<div class="container col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div>Session list template for {{trackid}}</div>
    <session-calendar callback-fn="ctrlFn()"></session-calendar>
</div>
```

My primary controller looks like this with the "eventClick" method I want to call.

```
angular.module('GAP.viewsessions', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('viewsessionsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){ 
    $scope.eventClick = function(eventData){
        console.log(eventData);
    }
}]);
```

Then the "SessionList" directive;

```
angular.module("GAP.sessionList", [])
.directive("sessionList", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
        },
        scope: {
            trackid: '@'
        },

        templateUrl: '/templates/sessionlist.html', // or use a path to a html file like 'path_to/template.html'
        replace: true,
    };
})
```

The other directive is a FullCalendar and in the click event of the event I have this;

```
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                scope.someCtrlFn();
                if (scope.eventClick){
                    scope.eventClick(calEvent.data);
                }
            },
```

And If I include this;

```
scope: { someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn' },
```

I get the previously quoted error.  If I leave it out, then the page renders but the "eventClick" method is never run in my controller.

Comment: One workaround is an angular event broadcast. Easier to help with a demo

Comment: Oh Wow.  Thanks @charlietfl.  Wrap that up in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is use an angular event

Inject `$rootScope` in directive then something like:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('cal-event-clicked', eventData)
```

In controller

```
$scope.$on('cal-event-clicked', function(evt, data){
   $scope.eventClick(data)
})
```